# Merge and match data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I am trying to collect data from 2 separate schemas. Due to the complexity of a singular query that would obtain all of the data would crash the database server, I made separate tables and filled them with the all of the data that I need. Now I just need to merge the data and match the columns so that I can remove any duplicate rows later. Below are the two queries that I created to return results that I am looking for. My problem is that when I run the second query, I get the following error :

```
   Error at Command Line:7 Column:4
   Error report:
   SQL Error: ORA-00904: "BOF_FOR_CHUCKSIMPSON"."BATCH_ID": invalid identifier
   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
   *Cause:    
   *Action
```

Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Query 1

```
 CREATE TABLE BOF_FOR_CHUCKSIMPSON AS
    SELECT 
    bbp.SUBCAR "Treadwell", HMM.LADLE "BOTTLE CAR",
    bbp.BATCH_ID "Batch ID",
    TO_CHAR(bbp.START_POUR, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:MI:ss') "Start Pour Time",
    TO_CHAR(bbp.END_POUR, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:MI:ss') "End Pour Time",
    TO_CHAR(hmm.sched_cast_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:MI:ss') "Sched Cast Date"
    FROM bof_batch_pour bbp, rouge.hmm_iron_cast_ladle@idbs1 hmm
    WHERE bbp.subcar=hmm.ladle
    AND TO_CHAR(hmm.sched_cast_DATE, 'yyyymmddhh24MIss') = TO_CHAR(bbp.SCHED_CAST_DATE, 'yyyymmddhh24MIss')
    AND bbp.START_POUR>='25-MAY-11';
    CREATE TABLE BOF_FOR_CHUCKSIMPSON2 AS
    SELECT bofcs.BATCH_ID "Batch ID", bofcs.sample_time "Sample Time",
    bcs.SILICON "Si", bcs.SULPHUR S, bcs.MANGANESE "Mn", bcs.PHOSPHORUS P,
    bofcs.TEMPERATURE "Temperature"
    FROM bof_chem_sample bcs, bof_celox_sample bofcs
    WHERE bofcs.SAMPLE_CODE                                   = bcs.SAMPLE_CODE
    AND bofcs.BATCH_ID                                        = bcs.BATCH_ID
    AND bofcs.TEMPERATURE                                    > 0
    AND bcs.SAMPLE_CODE                                       = 'D1'
    AND bofcs.SAMPLE_CODE                                   = bcs.SAMPLE_CODE
    AND bofcs.sample_time>'25-may-11'
    AND bofcs.sample_time<sysdate
```

Query 2

```
    merge into bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON2
    using bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON
    on (bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON.batch_id=bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON2.batch_id)
    when matched
    then
     update
    SET bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON.BATCH_ID = bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON2.bATCH_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
       THEN
          INSERT (bof_FOR_cHUCKSIMPSON2.bATCH_ID
              VALUES (99999);
```

Comment: try removing the alias for Batch_Id in query 1..

Answer (score 3):

You have used mix case names in double quotes in your create table statement like this:

```
bbp.BATCH_ID "Batch ID"
```

You don't therefore have a column in that table called BATCH_ID, but one called "Batch ID", and it can only be referenced thus - i.e. in mixed case and in double quotes.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed that by editing the column name in the table but I still get the same error.

Comment: If you still get _ORA-00904: "BOF_FOR_CHUCKSIMPSON"."BATCH_ID": invalid identifier_, then you still don't have a column called BATCH_ID in that table.